# who manages $HOME/.recently-used?

Tags: xdg

Who manages $HOME/.recently-used?

And is there a spec for it?

Could not find one, but maybe I am blind.

Comment: Various program usually manage it - mainly ones you save stuff from, and the file manager. Which version of Ubuntu are you using, and do you mean `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a [recent file specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/recent-file-spec/recent-file-spec-latest.html).